# Matrix Constraints CPLEX Python API

Tags: python, cplex

I am not sure how to insert mathematical symbols here. Anyways, I will try my best to explain what I want to achieve using a simple example here. So I have the following constraints:

```
For each k from 1 to 10
Sum_{i=1 to 5} p_ik * A_ik = Q_i
```

For example:

```
p_11 * [[1,1],[0,0]] + p_21 * [[1,0],[0,1]] = [[0.1,0.1],[0,0]]
```

where p_ik is a scalar decision variable and both A_ik, Q_i are matrices.
The constraints can be translated into the following linear constraints:

```
p_11 + p_21 = 0.1, p_11 =0.1, p_21 = 0
```

In fact, A_ik is a matrix of 0 or 1 which is quite sparse. I pre-computed the matrix A_ik and I am trying to add the above constraints. Or can I use make use of the class SparseTriple?

Comment: Are you asking how to use [quadratic constraints](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.QuadraticConstraintInterface-class.html)?  You probably already know this, but [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/preface/kindOfProblem.html) are the types of problems that CPLEX can solve (and more [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/preface/whatdoes.html)).

Comment: Not really. It should be linear constraints. In my example, it can be translated into:

`p_11 + p_21 = 0.1`
`p_11 =0.1`
`p_21 = 0`

Well, this example is too trivial..but it basically translates into the equations above.

Comment: Okay, you should probably edit your question to include that translated example.  If you're just creating linear constraints, you'll have to do the translation yourself and use the `Cplex.linear_constraints.add` method for them.  The `SparseTriple` class is only used for quadratic constraints.

Comment: @rkersh Just edited my question. I think I have a way to translate it into the input format of the `add_linear_constraints` function. Let me try it first thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the index of Q should be k instead of i, because you have a different Q in every k right?